# Intercept that a view controller will be displayed and do some stuff

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In my ios app I have several view controllers (Tab bar controller, view controller, table view controller, ...).

And I would like to detect when a view controller will be displayed (any of the view controllers I have). That way I would like to first check if the user is connected.

If he is connected then I let the view controller be displayed.
If he is not connected I would like to prevent the view controller to be displayed and I would like to display my login view controller.

What is the best way to perform this ?

Is there a way to intercept a view controller change to be able to stop it and do something else ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end they are sub-classes of `UIViewController`. You can have a `UIViewController`'s sub-class , called `MyBaseViewController` (for example) and on the method `viewWillApear:`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

 // Check connection here...

}
```

There you can create the logic for when the user is connected, or not.

Comment: When I present my modal view controller in the viewWillAppear function, it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use these instance methods on UIViewController, as a hook into events,

Responding to View Events

```
– viewWillAppear:
– viewDidAppear:
– viewWillDisappear:
– viewDidDisappear:
– viewWillLayoutSubviews
– viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use segues to go go from each view controller to the others, you can use:

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

You can make all the checks in that method of the current controller, and return `YES`or `NO`depending on the user state (connected, or not).

If you return `NO` the user will not navigate to the destination controller of the segue, and you can instead present the Login view controller.